# Does 'from modulename import function/variable' put entire module in the sys modules dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When we do `import modulename`, then functions and variables get setup in the modulename namespace (global). Any change made to variable for example is globally visible.

When we do `from modulename import function` or `variable`, then that function or variable gets loaded in calling modules namespace (local). Any change to variable is not global but only within the calling module.

However, does using `from modulename import function` or `variable` - put entire module in the sys modules? Or only the imported function/variable?

Comment: Inevitably, the entire thing. Basically because of the halting problem

Comment: So the entire imported module runs and only the function/variable comes into the callers namespace (local) where as the rest are all in the callee namespace (global)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you import just a selective set of names from a module, the module still needs to be fully compiled and executed for the specified names to be imported, so yes, using `from module_name import variable_name` does put the entire module into the module cache.

Since imported modules are cached in the `sys.modules` dict in Python, you can verify the behavior by outputting the difference between the keys of `sys.modules` before and after an importation:

```
import sys
modules = sys.modules.copy()
from math import sqrt # selectively import just sqrt from the math module
print(list(sys.modules.keys() - modules.keys()))
```

This outputs:

```
['math']
```

And you can then access other variables in the `math` module even though you imported only `sqrt` from `math`:

```
print(sys.modules['math'].pi)
```

This outputs:

```
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: When you say entire module is put in the sys.modules, what does this exactly does the sys.modules hold? Is it the module name or each of the function and variables in the module?

Comment: The entire module means the module object itself. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks. Just curios - Is it a good practice to use like this - sys.modules['math'].pi ?

Comment: Not a good practice. You should simply use the `from math import pi` statement to do that.

Comment: Also in your example sqrt is local and pi is global right? So if it were a variable instead of a function then change to pi will be local and change to sqrt would be globally visible?

Comment: No, `sqrt` becomes "global" to the `__main__` module, the main program itself, while `pi` remains just an attribute of the `sys.modules['math']` module object in my example.

Comment: But changing `sqrt` in main will not affect `math.sqrt` since `sqrt` is imported as a name under the main module. While changing `sys.modules['math'].pi` will affect `pi` under the `math` module, so it will affect everything else indeed.